# How to receive post/get request in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization

Im using

`$this->input->post('name') ;` to get a request posted to my url.Instead of post I need to access get as well.

Like in normal php its ,$_REQUEST is used.But what about in codeigniter standards,how is it possible?

Comment: $this->input->get('name') ; also show some code what you need?

Comment: the values passed with url , you can accept as argument in controller function

Answer (score 7):

It's outlined in the docs here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

To grab data from the `get` you can use

```
$this->input->get('some_data', TRUE);
```

That looks for `some_data` in the query string, and will run is through XSS filtering to clean it from possible hack attempts

There's also a handy method to check both at the same time:

```
$this->input->get_post('some_data', TRUE);
```

> "This function will search through both the post and get streams for data, looking first in post, and then in get"

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to post request from server

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){}

if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'GET'){}
```